# Simplest way to detect a mobile device in PHP

Tags: php, mobile

What is the simplest way to tell if a user is using a mobile device to browse my site using PHP?

I have come across many classes that you can use but I was hoping for a simple if condition!

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: You could put a javascript in the page that checks the screen resolution, but that would be client-side: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

Comment: Here is your solution: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect2/

Comment: Checking screen size these days is tricky because of retina devices.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

Here is a source:

- [Detect Mobile Browser](http://detectmobilebrowser.com/)
- [Download PHP script](http://detectmobilebrowser.com/download/php)

**Code:**

```
<?php

$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))

header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');

?>
```

Comment: Could HTTP_USER_AGENT be faked?

Comment: @naveed Just a heads up, this no longer seems to be working.  Tested in IOS 8.1 using Chrome's mobile browser.  Justin's is working for me though.

Comment: @kavior.com Yes it can be faked, but we should allow people to fake if they wish... because that would be their intention, why stop people from doing what they specifically want (i.e. load the desktop version for some reason in particular)?

Comment: This regex does not recognize facebook in-app browser.

Comment: this script will not detect ipad . please change ip(hone|od) to ip(hone|ad)

Comment: this answer is now so obsolete. there are many false positives, safari on OSX is detected as a mobile, Chrome on OSX detected as Mobile.

Comment: @DevZer0: Ok. You can add latest solution in the end of this answer.

Comment: What is the `substr($useragent,0,4)` part for?

Comment: Seeing this awesome post, there is no file in my host but PHP ones! PHP is excellent.

Comment: Not working for me while Justin DoCanto's way is working ok. Probably outdated answer

Comment: The answer is from 2010 and the most recent update on the referenced page is from 2014. Therefore I would not recommend using this solution, any more.

Comment: too old solution

Comment: @AbhayGawade: Too old question and answer as well

Comment: @datasn.io YES OF COURSE, I do data scraping and you can fake any user-agent :)

Comment: tested on iPhone Chrome version, and following user-agent was sent by client and it DIDNT detect as mobile `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/70.0.3538.75 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1`

Comment: This is a way old solution and it needs to be downvoted or replaced.

Comment: Well, not working for me. I don't know why it got such lot vote up.

Comment: @吳約南 It is 10 years old answer. I think you should ask a new question. You can share the latest solution here instead of downvoting.

Comment: @Naveed agreed. do you have it? (it wont work on Inspect mode for example)

Comment: @kmoney12 That's for getting just the first 4 characters of the user agent string. The rest of the string is not needed.

Answer (score 126):

I wrote [this script to detect a mobile browser](http://www.justindocanto.com/scripts/detect-a-user-on-a-mobile-browser-or-device) in PHP.

The code detects a user based on the user-agent string by preg_match()ing words that are found in only mobile devices user-agent strings after hundreds of tests. It has 100% accuracy on all current mobile devices and I'm currently updating it to support more mobile devices as they come out. The code is called isMobile and is as follows:

```
function isMobile() {
    return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
// Use the function
if(isMobile()){
    // Do something for only mobile users
}
else {
    // Do something for only desktop users
}
```

To redirect a user to your mobile site, I would do this:

```
// Create the function, so you can use it
function isMobile() {
    return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
}
// If the user is on a mobile device, redirect them
if(isMobile()){
    header("Location: http://m.yoursite.com/");
}
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey - im confused. they are all asking basically the same thing so what am i supposed to do, other than answer the question? tell them to use something else each time? i'm new here so im not sure if im supposed to link to the first answer?

Comment: This keyword "tablet" is creating me a problem on some IE8 (PC) headers that have "Tablet PC 2.0" in response

Comment: Why using a function to store the condition instead of a simple variable and do `if($isMobile) {}`?

Comment: Here is updated version: `return preg_match("/(android|webos|avantgo|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|opera mini|kitkat|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);` This is collection of few new devices.

Comment: Another update/mod: [`/\b(?:a(?:ndroid|vantgo)|b(?:lackberry|olt|o?ost)|cricket|docomo|hiptop|i(?:emobile|p[ao]d)|kitkat|m(?:ini|obi)|palm|(?:i|smart|windows )phone|symbian|up\.(?:browser|link)|tablet(?: browser| pc)|(?:hp-|rim |sony )tablet|w(?:ebos|indows ce|os))/i`](https://regex101.com/r/zQ3uU6/1)

Comment: When I echo its output, i get `0`. Why is that?

Answer (score 25):

I found [mobile detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) to be really simple and you can just use the `isMobile()` function :)

Comment: @showdev it does not detect desktop chrome "Inspect" mode (Instead, it thinks its a mobile)

Comment: @showdev did you solve this issue somehow by now?

Comment: FYI, this library is not updated for PHP 8 and causes a hard failure. Could be very useful but needs some attention.

Answer (score 21):

```
function isMobileDev(){
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
       $user_ag = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
       if(preg_match('/(Mobile|Android|Tablet|GoBrowser|[0-9]x[0-9]*|uZardWeb\/|Mini|Doris\/|Skyfire\/|iPhone|Fennec\/|Maemo|Iris\/|CLDC\-|Mobi\/)/uis',$user_ag)){
          return true;
       };
    };
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Simply you can follow the link. its very simple and very easy to use. I am using this. Its working fine.

http://mobiledetect.net/

use like this

```
//include the file
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
 //do some code
}

// Any tablet device.
if( $detect->isTablet() ){
 //do some code
}
```

Comment: does not work since it recognizes the desktop chrome Inspect mode as mobile

Comment: does not work in PHP 8.0 and up

Answer (score 9):

I was wondering, until now, why someone had not posted a slightly alteration of the accepted answer to the use of [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) in order to have a better readability of the code. So here it goes:

```
<?php
$uaFull = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$uaStart = substr($uaFull, 0, 4);

$uaPhone = [
    '(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile',
    'avantgo',
    'bada\/',
    'blackberry',
    'blazer',
    'compal',
    'elaine',
    'fennec',
    'hiptop',
    'iemobile',
    'ip(hone|od)',
    'iris',
    'kindle',
    'lge ',
    'maemo',
    'midp',
    'mmp',
    'mobile.+firefox',
    'netfront',
    'opera m(ob|in)i',
    'palm( os)?',
    'phone',
    'p(ixi|re)\/',
    'plucker',
    'pocket',
    'psp',
    'series(4|6)0',
    'symbian',
    'treo',
    'up\.(browser|link)',
    'vodafone',
    'wap',
    'windows ce',
    'xda',
    'xiino'
];

$uaMobile = [
    '1207', 
    '6310', 
    '6590', 
    '3gso', 
    '4thp', 
    '50[1-6]i', 
    '770s', 
    '802s', 
    'a wa', 
    'abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)', 
    'ai(ko|rn)', 
    'al(av|ca|co)', 
    'amoi', 
    'an(ex|ny|yw)', 
    'aptu', 
    'ar(ch|go)', 
    'as(te|us)', 
    'attw', 
    'au(di|\-m|r |s )', 
    'avan', 
    'be(ck|ll|nq)', 
    'bi(lb|rd)', 
    'bl(ac|az)', 
    'br(e|v)w', 
    'bumb', 
    'bw\-(n|u)', 
    'c55\/', 
    'capi', 
    'ccwa', 
    'cdm\-', 
    'cell', 
    'chtm', 
    'cldc', 
    'cmd\-', 
    'co(mp|nd)', 
    'craw', 
    'da(it|ll|ng)', 
    'dbte', 
    'dc\-s', 
    'devi', 
    'dica', 
    'dmob', 
    'do(c|p)o', 
    'ds(12|\-d)', 
    'el(49|ai)', 
    'em(l2|ul)', 
    'er(ic|k0)', 
    'esl8', 
    'ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)', 
    'fetc', 
    'fly(\-|_)', 
    'g1 u', 
    'g560', 
    'gene', 
    'gf\-5', 
    'g\-mo', 
    'go(\.w|od)', 
    'gr(ad|un)', 
    'haie', 
    'hcit', 
    'hd\-(m|p|t)', 
    'hei\-', 
    'hi(pt|ta)', 
    'hp( i|ip)', 
    'hs\-c', 
    'ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)', 
    'hu(aw|tc)', 
    'i\-(20|go|ma)', 
    'i230', 
    'iac( |\-|\/)', 
    'ibro', 
    'idea', 
    'ig01', 
    'ikom', 
    'im1k', 
    'inno', 
    'ipaq', 
    'iris', 
    'ja(t|v)a', 
    'jbro', 
    'jemu', 
    'jigs', 
    'kddi', 
    'keji', 
    'kgt( |\/)', 
    'klon', 
    'kpt ', 
    'kwc\-', 
    'kyo(c|k)', 
    'le(no|xi)', 
    'lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])', 
    'libw', 
    'lynx', 
    'm1\-w', 
    'm3ga', 
    'm50\/', 
    'ma(te|ui|xo)', 
    'mc(01|21|ca)', 
    'm\-cr', 
    'me(rc|ri)', 
    'mi(o8|oa|ts)', 
    'mmef', 
    'mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)', 
    'mt(50|p1|v )', 
    'mwbp', 
    'mywa', 
    'n10[0-2]', 
    'n20[2-3]', 
    'n30(0|2)', 
    'n50(0|2|5)', 
    'n7(0(0|1)|10)', 
    'ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)', 
    'nok(6|i)', 
    'nzph', 
    'o2im', 
    'op(ti|wv)', 
    'oran', 
    'owg1', 
    'p800', 
    'pan(a|d|t)', 
    'pdxg', 
    'pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))', 
    'phil', 
    'pire', 
    'pl(ay|uc)', 
    'pn\-2', 
    'po(ck|rt|se)', 
    'prox', 
    'psio', 
    'pt\-g', 
    'qa\-a', 
    'qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)', 
    'qtek', 
    'r380', 
    'r600', 
    'raks', 
    'rim9', 
    'ro(ve|zo)', 
    's55\/', 
    'sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)', 
    'sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)', 
    'sdk\/', 
    'se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)', 
    'sgh\-', 
    'shar', 
    'sie(\-|m)', 
    'sk\-0', 
    'sl(45|id)', 
    'sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)', 
    'so(ft|ny)', 
    'sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )', 
    'sy(01|mb)', 
    't2(18|50)', 
    't6(00|10|18)', 
    'ta(gt|lk)', 
    'tcl\-', 
    'tdg\-', 
    'tel(i|m)', 
    'tim\-', 
    't\-mo', 
    'to(pl|sh)', 
    'ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)', 
    'tx\-9', 
    'up(\.b|g1|si)', 
    'utst', 
    'v400', 
    'v750', 
    'veri', 
    'vi(rg|te)', 
    'vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)', 
    'vm40', 
    'voda', 
    'vulc', 
    'vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)', 
    'w3c(\-| )', 
    'webc', 
    'whit', 
    'wi(g |nc|nw)', 
    'wmlb', 
    'wonu', 
    'x700', 
    'yas\-', 
    'your', 
    'zeto', 
    'zte\-'
];

$isPhone = preg_match('/' . implode($uaPhone, '|') . '/i', $uaFull);
$isMobile = preg_match('/' . implode($uaMobile, '|') . '/i', $uaStart);

if($isPhone || $isMobile) {
    // do something with that device
} else {
    // process normally
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have the arguments of the implode() backward, _i.e._, I think the separator, the '|', ought to come first, and the arrays, $uaPhone and $uaMobile, ought to come second.

Comment: @JamesNorris > Your comment becomes right as of PHP 8.0.0. My syntax is valid prior to PHP 7.4.0, is deprecated from 7.4.0 and is falsy in PHP 8.0.0. I won't amend my answer though as it was valid at the time of writing. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php 

//-- Very simple way
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$iPod = stripos($useragent, "iPod"); 
$iPad = stripos($useragent, "iPad"); 
$iPhone = stripos($useragent, "iPhone");
$Android = stripos($useragent, "Android"); 
$iOS = stripos($useragent, "iOS");
//-- You can add billion devices 

$DEVICE = ($iPod||$iPad||$iPhone||$Android||$iOS);

if (!$DEVICE) { ?>

<!-- What you want for all non-mobile devices. Anything with all HTML, PHP, CSS, even full page codes-->

<?php }else{ ?> 

<!-- What you want for all mobile devices. Anything with all HTML, PHP, CSS, even full page codes --> 

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no reliable way.  You can perhaps look at the [user-agent string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-agent_string), but this can be spoofed, or omitted.  Alternatively, you could use a GeoIP service to lookup the client's IP address, but again, this can be easily circumvented.

Comment: GeoIP wouldn't really help. Even if you could determine that their IP belongs to a mobile network, they could be tethering the connection to a desktop computer. If it's not a mobile network you really no nothing all can devices connect through Wi-Fi. Also you have the problem of maintaining a global database of IP ranges. Using the user agent, even though it's not perfect, I would assume is much more reliable. It's not like it's really a security issue to serve the wrong browser content, so who cares? If someone's spoofing the UA, they likely already know what they're getting themselves into.

Comment: Right you were 11 years ago, user agents are getting useless, e.g. they do not report Safari and Firefox iPad as mobile anymore. Chrome still does, but it will follow the suit soon, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to include `user_agent.php` file which can be found from [Mobile device detection in PHP](http://www.codexworld.com/mobile-device-detection-in-php/) page and use the following code.

```
<?php
//include file
include_once 'user_agent.php';

//create an instance of UserAgent class
$ua = new UserAgent();

//if site is accessed from mobile, then redirect to the mobile site.
if($ua->is_mobile()){
   header("Location:http://m.codexworld.com");
   exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

A much easier solution which seems like it would work in most instances:

```
function funcDeviceType() {

 // INFO ABOUT THE BROWSER/DEVICE USER IS VISITING ON
 $useragent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]; 

 if(stripos($useragent, "mobile")!== false){
      return "mobile device";
  }else{
      return "desktop or laptop computer";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your server supports get_browser (available since PHP 4), it's extremely simple. They have a built in function for what you're asking.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

```
<?php
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
if($browser['ismobiledevice']) { 
      // Device is mobile 
}
?>
```

Comment: While reading the documentation it occurs to me that this function is more or less just a wrapper to the user agent header which returns it parsed as an array. Am I wrong?

Comment: It provides a lot more data vs the user agenda header as long as your server admin has browscap.ini. It can inform you what the browser supports and is a lot easier than having to put in all the regex people are writing.

Comment: It's _shorter_ — no doubt about that. I just noticed that they are based on the same data more or less.

Comment: @shaedrich Using the built-in function also has the advantage of being updated as new mobile devices (and new versions of user agent strings) are released.

Comment: for me, it will not working when I open webpage in mobileview in chrome.  Rather `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` is working as intended

Answer (score 2):

[PHP device detection from 51Degrees.com](http://51degrees.com/Support/Documentation/PHP) does exactly what you want - detects mobile devices and various properties associated with detected devices. It is simple to use and requires no maintenance. Set up is done in 4 easy steps:

1. Download the Zip file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/fiftyone/.
2. Unzip the file into a directory in your PHP server.
3. Then add the following code to your PHP page:
  ```
  require_once 'path/to/core/51Degrees.php';
  require_once 'path/to/core/51Degrees_usage.php';
  ```
4. All available device information will be contained in $_51d array:
  ```
  if ($_51d['IsMobile'])
  {
      //Start coding for a mobile device here.
  }
  ```

51Degrees device detector does not use regular expressions for detections. Only important parts of HTTP headers are used to match devices. Which makes this solution the fastest (5 000 000 detections per second on mediocre hardware) and most accurate (99.97% accuracy) as hundreds of new devices are added to the database weekly (Supported device types include consoles, smart TVs, e-readers, tablets and more).

Software is open source distributed under Mozilla Public License 2 and compatible with commercial and open source projects. As a bonus 51Degrees solution also contains a complementary [PHP image optimiser](http://51degrees.com/Support/Documentation/PHP/Image-Optimiser) that can automatically resize images for mobile devices.

By default 51Degrees PHP device detector uses Lite data file which is free and contains over 30000 devices and 50 properties for each device. Lite file is updated once every 3 month. If you want to have a higher level of details about requesting mobile devices, then Premium and Enterprise data files are available. Premium contains well over 70000 devices and 100 properties for each device with weekly updates. Enterprise is updated daily and contains over 150000 devices with 150 properties for each.

[Full list of device properties](http://51degrees.com/Resources/Property-Dictionary).
[Compare data files](http://51degrees.com/Products/Device-Detection/Compare-Device-Data).

Comment: that software is annoying. no support for IIS, no php only library.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a third party api to do device detection via user agent string. One such service is [www.useragentinfo.co](https://www.useragentinfo.co). Just sign up and get your api token and below is how you get the device info via PHP:

```
<?php
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
// get api token at https://www.useragentinfo.co/
$token = "<api-token>";
$url = "https://www.useragentinfo.co/api/v1/device/";

$data = array('useragent' => $useragent);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-type: application/json";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Token " . $token;

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($status != 200 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}

curl_close($curl);

echo $json_response;
?>
```

And here is the sample response if the visitor is using an iPhone:

```
{
  "device_type":"SmartPhone",
  "browser_version":"5.1",
  "os":"iOS",
  "os_version":"5.1",
  "device_brand":"Apple",
  "bot":false,
  "browser":"Mobile Safari",
  "device_model":"iPhone"
}
```

Comment: This works ! And this simple script seems one of the best i found : (until now) it's the only script i found which can detect my ASUS ZenPad tablet ! But NOTE : they changed the $url to [https://useragentinfo.co/device](https://useragentinfo.co/device), see their page [https://useragentinfo.co](https://useragentinfo.co) : it gives bash code to execute curl but indeed you can replace this by your PHP lines. However, you should omit the line "Authorization: Token .." because it seems no longer needed (and i see no way to get that API key).

Comment: Not getting response. just showing {}
I think API token is needed can you please guide me how to generate the token.

Comment: $data = array('user_agent' => $useragent);
It should be as : $data = array('useragent' => $useragent);

Comment: What if the domain is not reachable?

Comment: domain no longer available. Is there a new one?

Answer (score 0):

```
function isMobile(){
   if(defined(isMobile))return isMobile;
   @define(isMobile,(!($HUA=@trim(@$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))?0:
   (
      preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|silk|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i'
      ,$HUA)
   ||
      preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i'
      ,$HUA)
   )
   ));
}

echo isMobile()?1:0;
// OR
echo isMobile?1:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you care about screen size you can store screen width and Height as cookie values if they do not exists yet and then make self page redirection.

Now you have cookies on client and server side and can use it to determine mobile phones, tablets and other devices

Here a quick example how you can do it with JavaScript. 
Warning! [this code contain pseudo code].

```
if (!getcookie("screen_size")) {
    var screen_width = screen.width;
    var screen_height = screen.height;
    setcookie("screen_size", screen_width+", " +screen_height);
    go2(geturl());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
{
    echo('This is mobile device');
}
else
{
   echo('This is Desktop/Laptop device');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution

```
if(
    
    strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Phone')
    |
    strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Android')
    
    
){      echo "should be mobile";                }
else{   echo "give them the desktop version";   }
```

works with most devices i tested (via the browser dev tool device emulation) .

For sure, you can simply look at the used values yourself using `echo($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);`.

The only missing smartphone devices in my case were the BlacBerryZ30 which i fixed by checking for `'Touch'` as well. And for the Nokia N9 i checked for `'Nokia'` as well. One could obviously add these for many more deivces if found to be 'unchecked'. But for now this may be better/faster to understand than some of the more complex above string scanning patterns.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe combining some javascript and PHP could achieve the trick

```
<?php
$string = '<script>';
$string .= 'if ( /Opera|OPR\/|Puffin|Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { ';
$string .= '        alert("CELL")';
$string .= '    } else {';
$string .= '        alert("NON CELL")';
$string .= '    }       ';  
$string .= '</script>'; 
echo $string;
?>
```

I used that with plain javascript also instead

Comment: but it will recognize Desktop Chrome on Inspect mode as mobile (though its a nice concept)