# How to detect between mobile & tablets in PHP

Tags: php, html, mobile, tablet, responsive-design

I read on this thread:
[Simplest way to detect a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)
on how to know if the browser is a mobile device. the general code is this:

```
<?php include("Mobile_Detect.php"); include("demoData.php");
$detectIsMobile = new Mobile_Detect(); ?>
```

The problem is that I want to treat tablets (iPad & xoom).

I saw there that there is a isIpad() function that I have tested yet - but that still doesn't solve the difference between tablets and mobile phones.

Any idea?

thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
<?php
    if($detect->isTablet()){
        // any tablet
    }
?>
```

You can refer this page for more info http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Comment: @Arif Please Provide more details and please make sure that you follow all the guidelines in the given link.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is with a huge lookup table of `User-Agent:` strings.

[`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) would probably be able to do what you want, but you would need to make sure that you keep the [browscap](http://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.browscap) file *very* up to date - new tablet models are being released on a weekly basis.

Alternatively there may some Javascript way to do it (although I don't know what that might be) but

- you would still have to keep a very large lookup table updated
- you should never *rely* on Javascript for any kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
$detect = new Mobile_Detect; 
$deviceType = ( $detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
echo $deviceType;
```