# Only execute JS function on desktop computers (parallax plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

Is there any way I can restrict the execution (if statement) of javascript so that it only applies to desktop computers, It needs to be off when the user is on a mobile/tablet device.
Below is the code, however obviously it applies for any device at the moment when the document is ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    main_parallax();
    main_scrolling();
    sauces_slider();
});    
</script>
```

Only the `main_parallax();` function should be omitted when on a mobile/tablet device.

Comment: You Could Take a Look at the Useragent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device

Comment: Why does the effect need to be off on *all* mobile devices? Many tablets are strong enough to do all sorts of complex graphical things. Isn't this rather an issue of display resolution?

Comment: You might want to look at [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com), which makes it easy to test for "touch" events. There's no really solid way, no matter what library you use, to detect whether a device is a "mobile" device.

Comment: the parallax doesn't work properly on any device apart from desktop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method is using the **user agent**, which you could do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|webOS/i.test(navigator.userAgent) === false) {
        main_parallax(); //Run main_parallax() not a mobile device
    }​

    main_scrolling();
    sauces_slider();
});
```

I would recommend using **feature detection** instead, try looking into: [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)