# How to make css grid only appear on phone but not on desktop

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to make css grid appear on a phone version but i want only basic css with flexbox appear on desktop version.My website will be mobile first because its gonna be image gallery.

Comment: Look at CSS media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive css styles on mobile devices ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061520/responsive-css-styles-on-mobile-devices-only)

Comment: You can google it with this query: "css mobile only"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), such as :

```
// will be applied by default
.element {
    display: grid; 
}

// will overwrite the display when the screen has a larger width than 768px
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .element{
        display: flex; 
    }
}
```