# How to remove :hover on phones after <a> is clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I implemented "scroll to top" arrow from [this codepen](https://codepen.io/rdallaire/pen/apoyx) on my website:

jQuery:

```js
// ===== Scroll to Top ==== 
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {        // If page is scrolled more than 50px
        $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200);    // Fade in the arrow
    } else {
        $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200);   // Else fade out the arrow
    }
});
$('#return-to-top').click(function() {      // When arrow is clicked
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop : 0                       // Scroll to top of body
    }, 500);
});
```

CSS:

```css
#return-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
    -moz-border-radius: 35px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#return-to-top i {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 16px;
    top: 13px;
    font-size: 19px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#return-to-top:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
#return-to-top:hover i {
    color: #fff;
    top: 5px;
}
```

It works good on desktop, but has a problem on phone screens. When the arrow is clicked and the screen scrolled to top, if we scroll down again, the arrow gets shown in :hover state.

How can I "unset" the hover after the click?

EDIT:

Here's a screencast that shows the problem: https://streamable.com/5wr27

Comment: if everything else fails, maybe try to remove and recreate it instead of hiding or add `hover` via `jQuery` not via `CSS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `:hover` state you are referring to is lost when a mouse leaves the element, then all styles applied to such state are also lost, returning the element's styles to their originals.

This behavior does not happen in a mobile device screen since you have to press it with something, rather than just *hovering* over it. In this case the element retains the styles applied when pressing it, instead of losing them (as would happen when the mouse leaves the element).

All you have to do is return the element to its previous state manually, could be this:

```js
// ===== Scroll to Top ==== 
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) { // If page is scrolled more than 50px
    $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200); // Fade in the arrow
  } else {
    $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200); // Else fade out the arrow
  }
});
$('#return-to-top').click(function() { // When arrow is clicked
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0 // Scroll to top of body
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
#return-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
  -moz-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#return-to-top i {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 16px;
  top: 13px;
  font-size: 19px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#return-to-top:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

#return-to-top:hover i {
  color: #fff;
  top: 5px;
}

#return-to-top:not(:focus),
#return-to-top:not(:active) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#return-to-top:not(:focus) i,
#return-to-top:not(:active) i {
  top: 13px
}


/* Extra Things */

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

h3 i {
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Return to Top -->
<a href="javascript:" id="return-to-top"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>


<!-- ICON NEEDS FONT AWESOME FOR CHEVRON UP ICON -->
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Test the scroll -->
<div style="height:2000px;">

  <h3>Scroll down</h3>
  <h3><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>

</div>
```

You can also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061520/responsive-css-styles-on-mobile-devices-only) to apply those styles ONLY for mobile devices.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I've been scrolling the page up and down trying different things for way more hours than I'd like to admit. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just try 
javascript:

```
<a onclick="this.blur();">Top</a>
```

OR

```
$('#return-to-top').click(function() {
$(this).blur();
 $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop : 0                       // Scroll to top of body
  }, 500);
});
```

CSS:

```
#return-to-top:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have a :hover effect on touchscreens.

Instead maybe use a :active or :clicked selector inside a media query

```
media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    return-to-top:active {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    }
}
```

Something like that maybe?
You can look up the right widths to use.

Comment: Yeah that's what kind of confuses me. I'm currently inspecting it on Chrome and using device toolbar to recreate phone screen. After the arrow gets clicked, and later it is shown again, it seems to have all the :hover styles applied to it.
I also tested it with my phone, same happens.

Comment: I tried styling :active to be the same as the element without :hover, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what is happening is that the :hover is always attached so it is been considerated as being hovered. So you need to remove the hover. I found that the solution can be by add

```
$('yourelement').die('click');
```

I hope that this solution helps you.

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {        // If page is scrolled more than 50px
     $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200);    // Fade in the arrow
  } else {
     $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200);
     $('a').die('click');
   // Else fade out the arrow
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help either. I added a screencast to the question so it's clearer.