# redirect website from different user agent in php

Tags: php, redirect

How do I redirect website from different user agent? for example I want to redirect website from following user agent

1. **from desktop**: redirect to Link1
2. **from iphone**: redirect to Link2
3. **from android**: redirect to Link3
4. **from windows**(say all versions):  redirect to Link4
5. **other**: redirect to Link4

How do I achieve this in php?

**EDIT:** actually I don't the way of using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` for user agents that i had mentioned. I have checked the answers of stackoverflow regarding this but don't know how to use that.

Comment: Check if it's using a mobile here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228937/php-check-if-the-page-run-on-mobile-or-desktop-browser

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Comment: You could also use Mobile Detect (http://mobiledetect.net) to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/p/http_user_agent.htm) useful

[Here's a good example](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/article.php/3888106/How-Can-I-Detect-the-iPhone--iPads-User-Agent.htm):

```
<?php
    if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod')){  
        header('Location: http://yoursite.com/iphone');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

OR if you wanted to go by browser, you might find [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) useful

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the user agent of someone connecting to you.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

You might want to consider taking a look at this.
[Simplest way to detect a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)