# HTML5 audio player for website and mobile usage

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a page that has multiple instances of HTML5 audio players on it (it has multiple .mp3 links, that I want to be playable).

I want to develop **my own custom HTML5 audio player**, with my own graphics and stuff, and the main thing that I want is to have **bigger controls** (play button, music scroll, volume knob etc) ONLY for the [**mobile/Android**] version of the page.

Is that possible ? To have **different control sizes** (**play, pause etc.**) for different **screen-resolutions** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with using the @media Rule you can do exactly what you want
[CSS3 @media Rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

and there is another document that helps you found if the page is being viewed by Mobile/Tablet/PC and etc...

[Link to Document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15229056/4432956)

Comment: So you say that basically I will use the @media rule to specify the "play" button class has another ".jpg" source which will be bigger for mobile ?

Comment: yes. with @media you can set different resolutions for your images.