# How can I open a new activity based on the redirect in php

Tags: php, android

Please see this [link](http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/). Usually, when we login in forums, in the beginning, we see a welcome page using `php` code and session. In that link there are `html` codes and the `html` codes has been displayed in visitor machine.

The problem is, I do not want to use `html` code to display the welcome page in android device and I want create a separate layout for the welcome page and if the user can did successful login, he see the welcome layout.

I do not want a complete code from you. I know all of the codes in that link.But I do not want to use the `html` code in android and I have only welcome layout, so  my question is:

When  successful login the user, how `php` aware the android from user login and as the result the android application can choose a welcome layout for user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to detect a mobile device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)