# Add different code for mobile version

Tags: php, mobile

I have mobile browser detect variable named as `isMobile`. If it is `"True"`   browser is mobile, else is not. I want to add different Youtube player for mobile users by code below. But I couldn't succeed this so far.

```
if (!empty($_GET['isMobile']) and ($_GET['isMobile']=="True")){
echo '<iframe class="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/something" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';}
else{
echo '<iframe class="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/something" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';}
```

Comment: Did you try to use true without quotation?

Comment: In what way does this fail?

Comment: Sure. true without quotation is not string, it is boolean.

Comment: Yes i tried. It is not going in if section I think. Because when i say elseif (!empty($_GET['isMobile']) and ($_GET['isMobile']=="False")) for the else section, this time it is not going in else section either.

Comment: what you are looking for is http://mobiledetect.net/ it is a PHP class that will allow you to exactly that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Us the http://mobiledetect.net/ class. Then perform logic and partition and serve your content as you see fit.

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
    echo '<iframe class="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/something" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
} else {
    echo '<iframe class="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/something" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}
```

Though I should point out, Youtubes IFrame embed is already cross platform and browser capable, so this is all unnecessary.

```
<iframe class="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/something" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Will work in all browsers and mobile devices.

Comment: yes /embed/ code works for all platforms. but when playing playlists, it can't skip deleted videos. But /v/ code can.

Comment: hmm, sounds like a bug that should be reported to youtube. Another thing to consider is using a 3rd party wrapper to handle the video. Personally I like http://mediaelementjs.com/ which can handle playlists.

Comment: can i create youtube playlists by using it?

Comment: yessir, it's highly flexible, but more development intensive than just using YT's embed code.

Comment: last question: does mobile_detect.php file slow down my web site?

Comment: No, its just interpreting your request headers and is all server side, its one of the best and rock solid options for serving out different DOMs to different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing now is expect the *client* to send the parameter `isMobile`, as in

```
http://example.com/?isMobile=True
```

To detect mobile browsers, you might be able to use [Simplest way to detect a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device). To copy the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4117597/1587329) (adapted):

```
<?php

$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))) {
    echo '<iframe class="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/something" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
} else {
    echo '<iframe class="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/something" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}

?>
```

#### concerning `=="True"`

As another point, **do not use == for string comparison**. See [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp) for why it mostly does not do what you want it to. Teaser

```
0 == "0" == "00" == "000" == "0000" == "a"
```

This is because of type conversion, which does not happen for ===. Use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use lower case for variables and values. Array GET converted to lowercase all variables and values.

Comment: I have tried that too.