# How to Chnage root path when we access from mobile .htaccess?

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

Actually I have two sources

1. `Desktop Layout Support  (/Public_html/Desktop) (example.com)`
2. `Mobile Layout support   (/Public_html/Mobile) (example.com)`

How can i link root path based on  device access  without chnage/redirect domain in `.htaccess`.

Actually i Have tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample.in$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample.in$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !Public_html/Desktop/
RewriteRule (.*) /Public_html/Desktop/$1 [L]
```

But i can't able to find device

Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Please post your code!

Comment: Because device information is not found in either `HTTP_HOST` or `REQUEST_URI`.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here that you can try to create `loader.php` located in `/Public_html/loader.php` set it as root in .htaccess and when request comes to loader.php detect device for example by method suggested here - [Simplest way to detect a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device) 
after detection you have 2 options to do

1) Easy option: redirect page to example.com/desctop or to example.com/mobile

2) Hard option: include nigher `/Public_html/Desktop/index.php` nigher `/Public_html/Mobile/index.php` which for sure requires a lot additional configuration of include pats in your both projects