# Remove an action based on screen size in WordPress / WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, media-queries

I've added an action via hook like this

```
function my_wc_function(){

//function codes here;
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title','my_wc_function' );
```

Now in my theme options, users have the option to remove this function, so I got this done:

```
if (get_option('wc_remove_function') == 1) {
 remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title','my_wc_function' );
}
```

Everything goes well but **my concern this**, I have another option in my Theme Options where they should be able to remove the same function only on mobile screens (*say less than 1024px*).

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to remove these options, you could just hide them with a media query? What do you want to do with `my_wc_function()` (add content, remove icon, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, with this function my_wc_function(), certain content will be hidden, a kind of hover effect. Since hover does not work on mobile, so it's not needed. The function is needed to show the hover effect, like hover on the product image, the price, and product details show up. So, it won't work on mobile and I want them to display those product details below each of the product image on small screens.

Comment: So, can't you simply use Media Queries? I know it's a better thing to not serve content that won't be displayed, but, well, if it's just for a div with price and product details, you can just hide them using CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try below code:

```
<?php
    // Create the function, so you can use it
    function isMobile() {
       return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
    }
    // If the user is on a mobile device, redirect them
    if(isMobile()){
       remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title','my_wc_function' );
    }
?>
```

For more info check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)

Comment: So it won't be based on screen size, but on device user agent?

Comment: Yes it base on device user agent. try this and check in mobile device it works.

Comment: I'm not the asker, but he asked to "Remove an action based on screen size". User agent != screen size.

Comment: yes i know that but based on screen size it not possible in php you can do that using javascript

Comment: It could be done using PHP to add a specific class (if needed) and using a CSS media query to hide it.

Comment: Yes we can hide but the action called so hide is not good option

Comment: Well, you're right, but 1 option called in the thousands Wordpress requests. The question is about screen size, media queries are the way to go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112673/discussion-between-mukesh-panchal-and-enguerranws).

Comment: Thanks @Mukesh. I am surely gonna try this now and update this thread. I know that with php it's not possible and I cannot use JS here as the function needs to be removed to display another function.