# Check user open the site in App or not

Tags: php, android

I am using following code for checking whether the user opened the site in App or not

```
    $ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    if(stripos($ua,'android') && stripos($ua,'mobile') !== false) {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "apppackagename") {
    echo "Opening with App";
    }
   }
```

But this is not working in some devices like.

> GT - S7582 Android Version 4.2.2

Is there any solution for this to work in old version devices?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you want to fix?

Comment: @greenapps please check my edit

Comment: What you want to fix is unclear.

Comment: The error which is displaying. or is there any other method to check whether site is opened from app or not in php ?

Comment: What do you want to fix on the displayed error? Please just answer. No new questions.

Comment: @greenapps I want to hide the error displaying > Undefined index: HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH and the feature should work as expected . Sorry for the late reply :)

Comment: Use isset() for that index to check if it exists before you try to get its value.

Comment: Use phpinfo() to see which indexes are implemented for the used php version on that server.

Comment: Then use the function isMobile() mentioned in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10989524/1564978)

Comment: How do you set the header in your app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply include in the top https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/master/Mobile_Detect.php It's a lightweight library and requires to include only a single file.

for example:

```
 require_once('Mobile_Detect.php');
 $device = new Mobile_Detect();

 if ($device->isMobile() ) {
   if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
       $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "apppackagename") {
           echo "Opening with App";
       }
 }
```

if you want to detect android then you can type:

```
$device->isAndroidOS()
```

It's the most reliable way to detect a mobile device ( but also no bullet proof ). There is no way for reliable mobile detection with simple User Agent Check.

If you look into the source https://raw.githubusercontent.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/master/Mobile_Detect.php, you can see that GT-S7582 is supported.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use a library that has a stable set of checks for mobile/app detection. The upside of this is that you can expect the framework to support upcoming devices by simply upgrading your library instead of recoding it yourself.

For PHP there seems to be Mobile-Detect, it is open source and has active contributions: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

Comment: Thanks for the reply :).This is helpful. But I don't want to use library

Answer (score 1):

If you want hide the error you need use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) in you code like this:

```
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(stripos($ua,'android') && stripos($ua,'mobile') !== false) {
    if(array_key_exists('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH', $_SERVER) {
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "apppackagename") {
            echo "Opening with App";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry... I don't see a package!";
    }
}
```

The function `array_key_exists` "*Checks if the given key or index exists in the array*".

> Maybe in the future you need hide another errors, so, you can use @ to
>   *mute* error. [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).