# Is it possible to have a form POST the type of device used on submit?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'd like to know what type of device users are using when they submit a form on my website.

EDIT: I'm curious about more information than just mobile. iPhone, iPad, Android? Windows? Mac?

Is it possible with some javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device

Comment: You can check the brwser's header to identify the device, there are libraries like http://mobiledetect.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the answer here:

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Use this script to assign the device type to a hidden form field, then you can post it.

Answer (score 1):

you can cheek against the user agent and use some API like [useragentstring](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/api.php) to get all the data you want