# Detect mobile device in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, templates

I have a slider, it shows 4 videos, I need to show the picture when I go through with mobile device, video when through a desktop , the slider is written in `main.min.js`, and includeed in the `main.tpl`(template), and i have a script that detect mobile device

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {

}

// Any tablet device.
if( $detect->isTablet() ){
```

what should i do to show the picture when I go through with mobile device, video when through a desktop?

Comment: did you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4117597/4459647

Comment: You should **not** use php to determine user device, since php is a server side language, it is not a good  way to do that. you can easily use CSS and/or JS/jQuery to identify user device since they work on client side,

Comment: @Vishwa What's wrong with detecting the device at the server-side? Knowing the device you can offer a customized version of your page for specific devices.

Comment: @vishwa so which way do you suggest? and what should i write

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to check by user agent. WordPress has a wp_is_mobile fucntion in it's core that might help (I've removed WP parts of it):

```
function is_mobile() {
    if ( empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ) {
        $is_mobile = false;
    } elseif ( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile' ) !== false // many mobile devices (all iPhone, iPad, etc.)
        || strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android' ) !== false
        || strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Silk/' ) !== false
        || strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Kindle' ) !== false
        || strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry' ) !== false
        || strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini' ) !== false
        || strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mobi' ) !== false ) {
            $is_mobile = true;
    } else {
        $is_mobile = false;
    }
    return $is_mobile;
}
```

For detecting if a mobile device is a tablet or a phone, I don't think user agent help much. here is a list of tablet user agents that I found: [Tablet User Agents](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/hardware_type_specific/tablet/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this class http://mobiledetect.net, it's best for detecting different devices.

```
// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
    // Show the image here for mobile
}

if ( !$detect->isMobile() ) {
    // Show the image here for computer
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for php >= 8
https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/3.74.x/README.md

Comment: v4.8.x supports >=8: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/4.8.x/README.md