# How to get Screen Size in PHP with JavaScript with Conditions

Tags: javascript, php

Trying to get Screen Size from JS in PHP working

but if else conditions same value return

Please Update Questions if you understand my questions

i want to try this code not other

```
$screenwidth = "<script>

    var mobilewidth = console.log(screen.width); 

    if(mobilewidth < '768'){
        document.write('Mobile');
    }else{
        document.write('Template');
    }   


</script>";
echo $screenwidth;
```

> Output = Template or Mobile in both conditions
>
> in PHP

```
function LoadTemplate() {
    $screenwidth = "<script>document.write(screen.width); </script>";

if($screenwidth<=768){
    return 'Mobile';
}else{
    return 'Template';
}    
}
```

> Output = Template or Mobile both conditions

How to fix this please help

Comment: PHP is executed on server side and Javascript on client side, so, PHP sends all contents to browser and only then Javascript starts its execution, they can't communicate each other with a single piece of code, you need to use another way, like AJAX or cookies, but maybe the best way is try to detect the device with PHP There are some libraries that gives you screen info. You can start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device

Comment: First you have error in your JS:
`var mobilewidth = screen.width; console.log(mobilewidth);` instead `var mobilewidth = console.log(screen.width);`

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Thanks it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log(screen.width)` will return `undefined`, so you shouldn't assign it to a variable. Just do

```
var mobilewidth = screen.width
```

and if you really want to log in then follow ir with `console.log(mobilewidth)`.

By the way, `mobilewidth` is a very misleading name for this variable. Call it something like `currentWidth`, if you need to make it a variable on its own, and use `mobilewidth` for the currently hard-coded `768` value.

And finally, compare to the number `768`, not the string `'768'`.

Comment: How to fix this 
`function CurrentWidth() { $CurrentWidth = "<script> var mobilewidth = screen.width; if(mobilewidth < 768){ document.write('Mobile'); }else{ document.write('Template'); } </script>"; echo $CurrentWidth; }`


<?php include ('/app/design/fronted/Questions/default/'. CurrentWidth() .'/html/footer.php'); ?>

**Output** call outside files  

Template
Warning: include(/app/design/fronted/Questions/default//html/footer.php): failed to open stream

Comment: Please create a new question, don't ask it in a comment on an answer to an unrelated one.