# How detect user mobile information such as brand and model?

Tags: php, jquery, mobile

I want to detect user mobile brand and model with PHP or jQuery or both.
I want to get for example Samsung as brand and Galaxy Note 10 as model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest way to detect a mobile device in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-php)

Comment: I want to get for example Samsung as brand and Galaxy Note 10 as model

Comment: You'd have to inspect the user agent of the client. Have you tried anything so far? Please include any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/
Try this PHP library, it can give you something like user-agent but in array.