# How to detect if the user is using mobile app?

Tags: php, mobile

So is there any way to detect if the user is using mobile app with php?

Comment: You can try get User-Agent from header

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest way to detect a mobile device in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-php)

Comment: If you mean an app and not a browser, I would think it's difficult to detect as the app could send anything it wants as a request and not need to follow any browser user agent data standards.

Comment: Yes, I mean a app. I know how to do this with browser but not with app. I have a advertisement of the app at my page and I don't want to show it on app anymore