# Allow access to a html page on certain devices

Tags: javascript, php, html, github

Is there any method so that i could disable my webpage for mobile phones. the website which i host must be accessible only through laptop or pc . Any user who accesses the website must get a message so as to open the website from a windows browser. Is there any php or script to do this?

Im currently using GitHub for my website.

I tried making a html script that searches for the user device but that came unsuccessful. I searched but didn’t find results. Sorry if i don’t have enough information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10989524/13231904 `if(isMobile()) exit;`

Comment: No idea why you would want to do that